# Setting up Domain Trust over NAT?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain, nat

Short summary of our situation.

I have two separate domains that we need to establish a one-way forest trust between. Domain 1 has native subnet of 172.18.xx and Domain 2 has native subnet of 10.162.xx.xx.

The two networks are connected via a VPN tunnel through two firewalls. The problem is that the 172.18.xx.xx subnet is already in use in the hosted environment so we have a NAT to 10.162.xx.xx.

We have created a conditional forwarder on both domain, as well as created the trust from Domain 1 to Domain 2. From Domain 1 to Domain 2, the trust validates fine, the problem starts with validation from Domain 2 to Domain 1 - it is unable to locate a domain controller and nslookup is unable to resolve the domain of Domain 1. The problem seems to be with the native IP being reported back by Domain 1 to Domain 2, instead of the NAT'd IP.

At this point I'm looking into what options we have to get Domain 1 to report back the NAT'd IP when DNS resolution is performed, as I believe this is the ultimate fix. DNS Stubzone, or DNS translation in Firewall? Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: You need to use a different network/address, and assign that to a domain controller in a separate site in your perimeter network.. There are many available networks to choose from that aren't 172.18.xx.xx.

Comment: Our primary issue is the devices must not be multi-homed, they need to be on different VLANs, and on a different network perimeter. It's a govt compliance issue due to being a high risk SCADA system.

Comment: Domain controllers should never be multi-homed. You don't need  multiple ip addresses for this.